# kubernetes daemonset won't restart after annotation change

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

i have a daemonset where the pods are getting their configuration from a configmap, so i wanted to automatically restart the daemonset when i update the configmap.
i saw this in helm docs: https://helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/#automatically-roll-deployments
so i ended up putting this in my code:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: fluentd-logzio
  namespace: fluentd
  annotations:
    config: {{ include (print $.Template.BasePath "/configmap.yaml") . | sha256sum }}
  labels:
    k8s-app: fluentd-logzio
    version: v1
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: fluentd-logzio
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: fluentd-logzio
        version: v1
    [...]
```

the annotation updates successfully but the daemonset won't restart. is it because it's not a deployment? i tried changing deployment annotation using `kubectl edit` and it also didn't trigger a restart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put the annotation on the pod template, not the daemonset:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: fluentd-logzio
  namespace: fluentd
  labels:
    k8s-app: fluentd-logzio
    version: v1
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: fluentd-logzio
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: fluentd-logzio
        version: v1
      annotations:
        config: {{ include (print $.Template.BasePath "/configmap.yaml") . | sha256sum }}
    [...]
```

that way the pod config changes and the pods will be recreated.